# no install buttons in extensions.gnome.org

Tags: debian, gnome, gnome-shell

I just got a new computer, and I wanted to install all the nice shell extensions I had on my old one. Both of them are running Debian 7.5, and have gnome shell version 3.4.2.

The only difference I could find is that my new computer has a 64 bit version of Debian, and my old one has a 32 bit version.

But now, when I go to https://extensions.gnome.org/, all the extensions look greyed out and there are no install buttons. [image: a screenshot. The reviews never load.]

Also, it looks like the user reviews just never load. Probably a related issue. They do load on my old computer.

Answer (score 1):

Probably here is the answer you are looking for:

> If you are using GNOME 3.4 or newer and installation still doesn't
>   work, check to make sure that the "GNOME Shell Integration" plugin is
>   installed and enabled in your browser preferences. Some browsers have
>   a feature, click-to-play, which make it so the plugin cannot start
>   without user intervention. Make sure that either
>   http://extensions.gnome.org is whitelisted for the click-to-play
>   feature, or click-to-play is turned off entirely. Check your browser's
>   help for more details.

~ [I'm using GNOME 3. Why can't I install extensions?](https://extensions.gnome.org/about/#no-detection)

In the same link there are some more troubleshooting steps, so you may want to take a look at those too.

Comment: I tried those. They didn't work.
Actually, I would have answered my own question, but there's a time limit on that for some reason. I installed graphics drivers, just because I needed to do that anyway, and all of a sudden it started working.